# DevOps: automatically restarting a failed container

Tags: docker, devops

What is a light-wight approach to restart a failed docker container automatically -- that is, without having to install and setup tools like Swarm or Kubernetes?

I am asking because I need to have some resilience for a running container in the event the container "stops" as a result of failure of the process that it's running.

Comment: What platform are you using to deploy your instances? AWS have a few services that can help you with this (ECS, beanstalk) and are pretty quick to setup. Google cloud have similar services that I'm not that familiar with. Docker also published a service feature in their latest release which might suit your needs - https://blog.docker.com/2016/06/docker-1-12-built-in-orchestration/

Comment: Hmm. Simple... resilient...Thanks for the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check first if you can add [restart policies to your `docker run` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart).

They are the built-in Docker mechanism for restarting containers when they exit.
If set, restart policies will be used when the Docker daemon starts up, as typically happens after a system boot.

For instance:

```
on-failure[:max-retries]
```

> Restart only if the container exits with a non-zero exit status.
>   Optionally, limit the number of restart retries the Docker daemon attempts.

If not, see "[Automatically start containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/host_integration/)"

Comment: Thanks this is great, and highly informative.  Even gives two options.